# Brushless DC motor power source

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I’m thinking of buying a brushless DC motor to power a watchmakers lathe, but I am hesitant because of the complicated looking, very expensive controllers and drivers that go between the motor and the wall outlet. I don’t need a variable speed controller, so it seems the only requirement is to reduce 120 V to 48 V and imagine there are simpler, much less costly, ways to do that. Can this be done?

Comment: Re, "I'm thinking of buying a brushless DC motor..." Why? If the motors that you're looking at seem to require "complicated looking, very expensive controllers..." then why not pick something different? What is your real goal?

Comment: For a watchmakers lathe you will find speed control via foot pedal, like a sewing machine, very useful indeed.

Comment: P.S., Nobody's going to be able to tell you how to provide power to the motor if you can't tell them what kind of power the motor requires. "Brushless DC..." often means that the motor "controller and driver" is built-in, and literally all you have to do is supply it with a DC voltage. Is that, in fact, what you are looking at?

Comment: My lathe has eight speeds via a 4 pulley, 3 shaft system. Two step pulley on the motor and a 4 step pulley on idler and spindle shafts. The BLDC motor will be 48v, 200W and 85 oz-in rated torque.

Comment: All the BLDC motors I've seen online have controllers and drivers as add ons or stand alone with lots of wires. I have not seen one with a cable with a standard three prong plug.